# Confused as to why these pictures and text aren't lining up

Tags: css, html

I have a div with 2 different divs in it. Each of these 3 have a picture in (60%) of the width and some text in them (40%) however it isn't lining up at all. The text is in the right place and the pictures are in the right organization but they are too far down the page. I'm newish to CSS and I don't know how to fix this

Here's a picture of what it looks like

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="section 1">
  <p id="section1text">
    <b>ME</b><br>Hello! My name is Max Jordan. I am a student living in the UK currently doing A-Levels in Maths, Engineering, Physics and computer science. I then want to do a degree in computer science and work as a Software Engineer/Developer. I currently live in Nottingham in the UK. I love programming and creating elegant solutions for problems.
  </p>
  <img src="section1.jpg" id="section1pic">
</div>

<div class="section 2">
  <p id="section2text">
    <b>WORK</b><br> 
  </p>
  <img src="section2.jpg" id="section2pic">

</div>

<div class="section 3">
  <p id="section3text">
  </p>
  <img src="section3.jpg" id="section3pic">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.aboutSection{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}

.section{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

#section1text{
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width:40%;
  background-color: #3399ff;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20;
  padding: 10px;

}
#section2text{
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width:40%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #3399ff;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
#section3text{
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width:40%;
  background-color: #3399ff;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

#section1pic{
  float: right;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
}
#section2pic{
  float: left;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
}
#section3pic{
  float: right;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
}
```

I know the CSS is very bad but im just trying to get it working.

Comment: can you give a little overview of how exactly it has to look

Comment: https://gyazo.com/22b24142b2d557e9fe2bdd4e9ee17b9f

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fiddling around with floats and positioning. I guess display:flex is a good option for such layouts

check this snippet

```css
.imgContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.section {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#section1text {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #3399ff;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  px solid;
}
.div1 img {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}
.div2 img {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.div3 img {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}
#section2text {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #3399ff;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20;
  padding: 10px;
}
#section3text {
  background-color: #3399ff;
  color: white;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgContainer">
  <div class="section div1">
    <p id="section1text">
      <b>ME</b>
      <br>Hello! My name is Max Jordan. I am a student living in the UK currently doing A-Levels in Maths, Engineering, Physics and computer science. I then want to do a degree in computer science and work as a Software Engineer/Developer. I currently live
      in Nottingham in the UK. I love programming and creating elegant solutions for problems.
    </p>
    <img src="https://exoticcars.enterprise.com/etc/designs/exotics/clientlibs/dist/img/homepage/Homepage-Hero-Car.png" id="section1pic">
  </div>

  <div class="section div2">
    <img src="https://exoticcars.enterprise.com/etc/designs/exotics/clientlibs/dist/img/homepage/Homepage-Hero-Car.png" id="section2pic">
    <p id="section2text">
      <b>WORK</b>
      <br>
    </p>


  </div>

  <div class="section div3">
    <p id="section3text">
      skfshfk
    </p>
    <img src="https://exoticcars.enterprise.com/etc/designs/exotics/clientlibs/dist/img/homepage/Homepage-Hero-Car.png" id="section3pic">

  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to create sample layout of your requirement

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You need to start with eliminating:

```
padding: 10px;
```

Or at least change it to:

```
padding: 10px 0;
```

This should be removed from `#section1text`, `#section2text`, and `#section3text`. The padding is causing your text sections to be wider than 40%, which does not leave the 60% width for the images.

Comment: Right, maybe even just adjusting the width to smaller values.

Comment: I did that and it still a little off, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yes, now you have an issue with a height difference between the images and text sections.

Comment: I would suggest looking at using `display:table-cell;` to match heights. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Any idea how to fix it? They are both set to 100% height]

Comment: Please see my last comment regarding `display:table-cell;` to fix height. The quick and dirty way would be to set height for the images and text sections in a non-percentage unit: `px`, `em`, `rem`, `vh`, `vw`, etc.

Comment: I just did that and its exactly the same as before :/

Comment: You did what? Added `display:table-cell;`?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.aboutSection{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.section{
position:relative;
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
width:90%;
overflow:hidden;
}

.aboutSection .section:nth-child(odd){
flex-direction:row-reverse;}

.section p{
width:40%;
margin:0;
padding:2px;
}

.section img{
flex:0;
width:auto;
min-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutSection">
<div class="section">
  <p>
    <b>ME</b><br>Hello! My name is Max Jordan. I am a student living in the UK currently doing A-Levels in Maths, Engineering, Physics and computer science. I then want to do a degree in computer science and work as a Software Engineer/Developer. I currently live in Nottingham in the UK. I love programming and creating elegant solutions for problems.
  </p>
  <img src="http://www.markgray.com.au/images/gallery/large/desert-light.jpg">
</div>

<div class="section">
  <p>
    <b>WORK</b><br> 
  </p>
  <img src="http://www.markgray.com.au/images/gallery/large/desert-light.jpg">
</div>

<div class="section">
  <p>
  </p>
  <img src="http://www.markgray.com.au/images/gallery/large/desert-light.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

i know you work so hard, but i think you need to read more about css and keep practice. You don't need any ID on this thing. And actually i don't really understand what is you wanted. Maybe something like this?